# Error running multiple Django production sites on Ubuntu 22.04/apache2

Tags: python-3.x, django, ubuntu, apache2

I am trying to host two virtual django sites on a ubuntu/apache2 setup.
Site number one works great. I mirrored the settings for site number two but I am getting error:

```
    [Fri Jun 02 18:27:24.041306 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22018:tid 140106201364352] mod_wsgi (pid=22018): Shutdown requested 'aww.exodustec.com'.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:24.048138 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22018:tid 140106201364352] mod_wsgi (pid=22018): Stopping process 'aww.exodustec.com'.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:24.049208 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22018:tid 140106201364352] mod_wsgi (pid=22018): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:24.049751 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22018:tid 140106201364352] mod_wsgi (pid=22018): Destroy interpreter 'aww.exodustec.com|'.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:24.050397 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22018:tid 140106201364352] mod_wsgi (pid=22018): End interpreter 'aww.exodustec.com|'.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:27.588319 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22145:tid 140106201364352] mod_wsgi (pid=22145): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:27.668319 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22145:tid 140106201364352] mod_wsgi (pid=22145): Adding '/aww/src/' to path.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:55.908422 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] mod_wsgi (pid=22145): Create interpreter 'aww.exodustec.com|'.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:55.913683 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] mod_wsgi (pid=22145): Adding '/aww/src/' to path.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:55.914667 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote] mod_wsgi (pid=22145, process='aww', application='aww.exodustec.com|'): Loading Python script file '/aww/src/awwcollectables/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.567455 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote] mod_wsgi (pid=22145): Failed to exec Python script file '/aww/src/awwcollectables/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.567620 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote] mod_wsgi (pid=22145): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/aww/src/awwcollectables/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578052 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578169 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578204 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]     import MySQLdb as Database
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578266 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578306 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote] 
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578340 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote] The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578374 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote] 
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578413 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]  Traceback (most recent call last):n 02 18:27:56.578542 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]   File "/aww/src/awwcollectables/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578577 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578616 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578650 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578731 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578765 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578803 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578836 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]     app_config.import_models()
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578874 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578907 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578944 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.578978 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579015 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote ]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579053 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579091 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote:42929]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579129 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579282 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579321 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579360 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579393 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579432 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 57, in <module>
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579466 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579503 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579537 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579574 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579608 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579646 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579695 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579734 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579767 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579805 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579838 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     conn = self.create_connection(alias)
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579876 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579909 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579947 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.579980 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.580018 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.580051 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.580089 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]   File "/aww/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.580123 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929]     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.580171 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
[Fri Jun 02 18:27:56.580205 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 22145:tid 140106168383040] [remote :42929] Did you install mysqlclient?
```

This host works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName rentcorp.exodustec.com

    ErrorLog /rentcorp/site/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /rentcorp/site/logs/access.log combine

    Alias /static /rentcorp/site/static/
    Alias /media /rentcorp/site/media/

    <Directory /rentcorp/site/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /rentcorp/site/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /rentcorp/src/rentcorp>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess rentcorp python-home=/rentcorp/venv python-path=/rentcorp/src/
    WSGIProcessGroup rentcorp

    WSGIScriptAlias / /rentcorp/src/rentcorp/wsgi.py

    <Directory /rentcorp/src/templates>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This host doesnt.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName aww.exodustec.com
 

    ErrorLog /aww/site/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /aww/site/logs/access.log combine

    Alias /static /aww/site/static/
    Alias /media /aww/site/media/

    <Directory /aww/site/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /aww/site/media>
        Require all granted
    
    </Directory>

    <Directory /aww/src/awwcollectables>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess aww python-home=/aww/venv python-path=/aww/src/
    WSGIProcessGroup aww
    WSGIScriptAlias / /aww/src/awwcollectables/wsgi.py

    <Directory /aww/src/templates>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```